# How to check the selected version of Qt in a .pro file?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qmake, qtgui

I have multiple versions of Qt installed, and I need to compile my project with all of them.
Using a pro file, I could not find in the documentation how to do a conditional compilation.

Ideally, this is what I would like to do:

```
QT_VERSION = 5   # this can be 4, set manually

if(QT_VERSION == 5) {
   QT += widgets
}
if(QT_VERSION == 4) {
   QT += gui
}
```

Naturally, the if() command does not exist in pro files.
Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: would cmake be an option?

Comment: I always use cmake when I can. I'm afraid this is not the case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use conditional functions and scopes here:

```make
QT_VERSION = 5   # this can be 4, set manually

equals(QT_VERSION, 5){
   QT += widgets
}
equals(QT_VERSION, 4) {
   QT += gui
}
```

However, there are a few things that you need to pay attention to in your original code:

1. Explicitly defining the Qt version is not necessary, and it can make you get a headache if you forgot to change that in the .pro file. Instead, qmake automatically defines a variable `QT_MAJOR_VERSION` for you.
2. Using `equals` will work in this case. However, as noted below, `equals` performs a string comparison. However, it is better to use `greaterThan` and `lessThan` because your code will automatically stop working when you try to compile it with Qt 6 (somewhere in the future).
3. Adding `gui` to the `QT` is not needed, as it is included by default.

So, your code should be:

```make
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
}
```

---

Here are some [undocumented `qmake` gems](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake):

- ```make
  defined(func, type)
  ```

  Returns true if `func` is defined; type must be either `test` or `replace`, to match `defineTest` or `defineReplace`.
- ```make
  equals(var1, var)
  ```

  (also works as `isEqual`).
  Returns true if var1 is equal to var2 (string comparison).
- ```make
  lessThan(var1, var2)`
  ```

  Returns true if `var1` is less than `var2` (as an integer).
- ```make
  greaterThan(var1, var2)
  ```

  Returns true if `var1` is greater than `var2` (as an integer).
- ```make
  inFile(file, var, val)
  ```

  Returns true if a variable `var` is defined in the specified file. Additionally, it can test to see if it has the requested value.
- ```make
  load(string)
  ```

  Something of a cross between `include()` and `CONFIG += [feature]`. `load(foo)` will look for a file called "foo.prf" in the standard feature path, and execute its contents immediately. Features that are contained within `CONFIG` are executed last, after the ".pro" file has finished processing. Like `include()`, it will return true if the file was found.

Answer (score 10):

You can make checks in one line like this:

```
equals(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5):!lessThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 5) {
   QT += bluetooth
} else {
  message(Qt $$QT_VERSION Bluetooth not supported.)
}
```

`!lessThan` there stands for greater or equal.

Answer (score 10):

Since Qt 5.10, there is [versionAtLeast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#versionatmost-variablename-versionnumber) and [versionAtMost](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#versionatmost-variablename-versionnumber) test functions.

Usage example:

```
!versionAtLeast(QT_VERSION, 5.11.2):error("Use at least Qt version 5.11.2")
```

P.S.: Posting this answer, since simple googling "qmake check Qt version" doesn't brings these references (but this post does).

Comment: Needs Qt 5.10 at least. See here: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/8a3e8856e5606ec616d4420ff8c4f77969432390

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple test to do. This is what we have been doing in [QtSerialPort](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/6bd56edb87f14074a15fde141d9d6f52d01de366:qtserialport.pro) and also some other modules inside the Qt framework:

```
lessThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Similar and common conditions are:

```
contains(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): ...
```

or:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): ...
```

[Here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/6bd56edb87f14074a15fde141d9d6f52d01de366:src/serialport/serialport.pro) you can find another QtSerialPort example we have been doing in there.