# QMainWindow: No Such File Or Directory

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, beagleboneblack

I'm using QT Creator 3.5.1 and QT 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS host machine, I configured my BeagleBone Kit for ARM crosscompiling like this:
 [image: QT for BeagleBone]

I'm following [these steps](http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter11/), but I'm getting an error when trying to compile the default QT project [image: QMainWindow Error]

Am I missing something? If it's not found, it is not located at place where compiler looks. **How do you fix this?**

Here is my project file

[image: Picture of my project]

Comment: Can you post your .pro file? you might be missing the "widgets" option in the QT variable.

Comment: I posted it. @HappyCactus

Comment: The sysroot field is suspicious. and check the kit configuration , that "!" yellow sign tells you that something's wrong.

Comment: What to do with sysroot? @HappyCactus

Comment: I tried with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663331/how-to-check-the-selected-version-of-qt-in-a-pro-file, but it won't work

Comment: where sysroot should point? @HappyCactus

Comment: It depends on your compiler. try to leave it empty, just in case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94085/discussion-between-zola-and-happycactus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mybe there was some error while your building qt from source, or something is missing. Try search QMainWindow.h in qt include dir. Seems like it is in `/usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/include`. For am example you can search like this `find * /usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/include/ | grep QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 9):

Using Qt 5.8.0 on Win 7 / MSVC2015x64bit;

I had the same issue and I found a way to fix it, even if its not the smartest:

1) Open your projectname.pro file

2) Between 
`QT   += core gui`
 and 
 `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, X): QT += widgets`
 paste `QT    += widgets`

 so this part looks kinda like this:

`...
 QT    += core gui
 QT    += widgets
 greaterThan(QT_MAJOR...`

Save and close the .pro file and wait for Qt to automatic read the
file-changes and updating itself.
(If you have deaktivated this try restart Qt)

Aswell as this - replacing the "X" at `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, X): QT += widgets` with the pre-version's number works fine for me. (`X = your_major_version - 1`)

(In case using Qt 5.x place a 4 instead of 5, using Qt 3.x replace 3 with 2 and so on...)

I dont know if this also works for other platforms...

I hope i could help at least 1 person who has the same issue. ;)

Greetings Zitro

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need make sure, that cross compiler works,
compile hello world: `std::cout << "hi\n"` and run on device using cross comipler gcc from command line.

Second step is making sure that qmake from cross compiled Qt works as expected, run `/usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/bin/qmake path/to/your/pro/file && make` if all works then next step

Third, at last configure your Qt Creator

Look here: http://developer.toradex.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux

You need set sysroot to right value, for example in my case this is:

> /usr/local/oecore-i686/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/

inside this directory there "bin" and "lib" full of arm executables and arm libraries, this is what "sysroot", it is part of your device file system cloned to your cross compiler, that help you link your applications. Also make sure that you set right path to qmake for cross compilation in Qt creator preferences, it should like this: `/usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/bin/qmake`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your QT Creator version is out of date. Projects can become corrupted if you install a version of QT Creator that is incompatible with them. You can download the latest version of QT Creator in the Software Center.

You also need to make sure your QT is up to date. Check using the Software Updater.

I found this; you might want to take a look at it: [derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/qt-with-embedded-linux-on-the-beaglebone/#Source_Code](http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/qt-with-embedded-linux-on-the-beaglebone/#Source_Code)

Answer (score 1):

On windows check that your project folder doesn't have strange characters like: ( , ) or # ...